# Nicer output of 'bridge link'

Tags: linux, networking, bridge, iproute2

The command `brctl` is being replaced by the `ip` and `bridge` commands.
With `brctl show` or `brctl show br0` it was possible to list all network devices that were connected to that bridge.

```
% brctl show br0
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.64006a668786       no              eth0
                                                        eth1
```

The `bridge link` command works the other way round:
It will list all network devices thar are part of a bridge and the name of that bridge for each device.

```
% bridge link
2: eth0 state UP : <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 4
3: eth1 state UP : <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 4
```

Is there a way to get a nice list of network devices that belong to a certain bridge like with the deprecated brctl (apart from `bridge link | grep br0`)?

Comment: Is your question asking for an output that is "nice" or an output showing only informations related to br0? because your example having only one bridge, not multiple, what you really want is unclear

Comment: I would actually like to do both.